# Condiciona SE aninhadas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Gostaria de criar um formula SE que usasse as seguintes condições:

```
1-Se A for maior ou igual a 1 e menor ou igual a 3 devolve B, caso não 0
2-Se A for maior ou igual a 4 e menor ou igual a 6 devolve B, caso não 0
3-se A for maior ou igual a 7 e menor ou igual a 9 devolve B, caso não 0
4-Se A for maior ou igual a 10 devolve B, caso não 0
```

Já tentei usar a seguinte fórmula que não resultou:

=IF(A1<=3,z1,0)
 Essa formula obrigaria me a calcular 4 vezes para obter o mesmo resultado. A minha dificuldade é sintetizar a fórmula para incluir todos os intervalos desde 1-3; 4-6; 7-9; 10-mais.

Comment: =IF(A1<=3,Z1,0)

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o que já tentou fazer, e explique sua dificuldade.

Comment: A minha dificuldade consiste em compor a formula que me devolva o resultado certo. Tentei usar essa que está aí em cima mas não está a resultar.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa combinar a função `SE` com a função `E`.

A função `SE` tem o seguinte formato:

```
SE(condição;resultado se verdadeiro;resultado se falso)
```

Já a função `E` tem o formato:

```
E(teste lógico 1;teste lógico 2;...)
```

No seu caso, precisa de algo assim:

```
=SE(E(A1>1;A1<5);B1;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que as fórmulas desejadas são essas:

```
=SE(E(A2>=1;A2<=3);Z2;0)   'cenário 1
=SE(E(A2>=4;A2<=6);Z2;0)   'cenário 2
=SE(E(A2>=7;A2<=9);Z2;0)   'cenário 3
=SE(A2>=10;Z2;0)           'cenário 4
```

O resultado deve ser algo assim, apesar de não saber como está sua planilha:

[image: Exemplo 1]

[image: Exemplo 2]